# Why is my VBA button behaving strangely on onAction call?

Tags: debugging, vba, button

I get the following message when my VBA button 's onAction method gets called. *The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled*

In the test.xlsm in ThisWorkbook file I have a very simple code

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UpdateMenuSR
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateMenuSR()
Dim cb As CommandBarButton
Dim Solver As CommandBar

For Each Solver In Application.CommandBars
    If Solver.name = "Test" Then Exit Sub
Next Solver

Set Solver = Application.CommandBars.Add("Test", msoBarFloating, False)
With Solver
    .Visible = True
    With .Controls
        Set cb = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        With cb
            .FaceId = 31
            .Visible = True
            .OnAction = "!b"
        End With
        Set cb = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        With cb
            .FaceId = 19
            .Visible = True
            .OnAction = "!c"
        End With
        Set cb = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        With cb
            .FaceId = 30
            .Visible = True
            .OnAction = "!a"
        End With
        Set cb = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        With cb
            .FaceId = 8
            .Visible = True
            .OnAction = "!d"
        End With
   End With
End With
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl
Application.CommandBars("Test").Delete
For Each ctrl In Application.CommandBars("Tools").Controls
    If ctrl.Tag = "Test" Or ctrl.Tag = "Test" Then
        ctrl.Delete
    End If
Next ctrl
End Sub
```

In the Main module I have only

```
Public Sub a()
MsgBox "a"
End Sub


Public Sub d()
MsgBox "d"
End Sub


Public Sub b()
MsgBox "b"
End Sub


Public Sub c()
MsgBox "c"
End Sub
```

If I do the following procedure:

- Create new file test2.xlsx
- Open test.xlsm
- Open test2.xslx
- Clicking one after another on the buttons:

Results in:
    "b"

```
"Cannot run the macro '[test.xslm]Sheet1A:A'. The macro may not be available in this   workbook or all macros may be disabled"

"a"

"Cannot run the macro 'd'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"
```

- Switch to test.xlsm

Results in:

```
 "b"

"Cannot run the macro '[test.xslm]Sheet1A:A'. The macro may not be available in this wo rkbook or all macros may be disabled"

 "a"

 "d"
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have hacked problem. Just add two unvisible buttons:

```
    Set cb = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With cb
        .Visible = False
    End With

    Set cb = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With cb
        .Visible = False
    End With
```

Therefore visible buttons work correctly.